# How to change path in Prestashop 1.3.1.1

Tags: database, path, settings, prestashop

Hello i want to change path in settings/folder.
I try change it in setting.
I try change path from "/" to "/something/" click save button. 
Seems OK, i get green notification, and my path is still "/".
Can i change this in database or something else is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change some data in the database

- go to your database, under PS_CONFIGURATION table change PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_SSL to your registered domain. (ex. www.example.com).
- go to your database, under PS_SHOPURL and change domain and domain_ssl to your registered domain. (ex. www.example.com).

im not sure in lower version of prestashop but this works for me in 1.6

Comment: In my database i don`t have that tables:
PS_SHOP_DOMAIN, PS_SHOP_SSL, PS_SHOPURL, domain_ssl.

Comment: what version are you using? maybe your PS in not your table prefix